# Iterating through a python dictionary with lists as values

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

I'm trying to iterate through a dictionary that looks like:

```
    d = {
    "list_one": [
        "hello",
        "two",
        "three"
    ],
    "list_two": [
        "morning",
        "rain"
    ]
}
```

I'm using the function:

```
def combine_words(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        a = {k: ("|".join(v))}
    return a
```

When I run this with print, my output is just one key, value pair. I'm not sure what is happening here. My ideal out put would be:

```
{
'list_one': 'hello|two|three',
'list_two': 'morning|rain'
}
```

Comment: What is the goal of the iteration? What is you expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` gets replaced by a new `dict` each time through your loop. You want a dict comprehension.

```
def combine_words(d):
    return {k: "|".join(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: That's what I thought, too, but the OP said it only shows the _first_ key-value pair not the last

Comment: If he's using anything earlier than Python 3.6, "first" doesn't really have any meaning when discussing the keys. It also doesn't really matter what the exact wrong output is.

Comment: Thank you, I meant to say "one" key, value pair. Edited in question!

Comment: Again, it doesn't matter. You're only getting one key/value pair because you are creating a new dict every time through the loop; which pair doesn't really matter. You want to be *adding* a new key/value pair to the *same* dict.

Answer (score 6):

```
def combine_words(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        a = {k: ("|".join(v))}
    return a
```

This constantly reassigns the dictionary to a, and isn't combining the results

```
def combine_words(d):
    a = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        a[k] =  ("|".join(v))
    return a
```

Would keep adding new entries to the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you change the value of `a` during every iteration of your `for` loop because you reassign `a`. You can modify your code to get around this:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    a[k] = "|".join(v)
```

Alternatively, you can use a dict comprehension:

```
return {k: "|".join(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```